# Is a hyphen necessary in the compound adjective "the already quite surprising idea"?

Tags: hyphenation, compound-adjectives

> [I just wrote]: The expression "you may/might (just) as well + infinitive" can be used sarcastically and emphatically to introduce a more exaggerated, extreme example than **the already quite surprising idea** mentioned in the preceding sentence.

In the case of a more-than-two-word compound adjective, the choice of whether to link some part of it with a hyphen(s) or not does not always come easily...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"The already quite surprising idea" actually isn't a compound adjective; it's a noun phrase, headed by the noun *idea*, and is parsed as "the [[already [quite surprising]] idea]".

However, "already quite surprising" is a multiword adjective phrase used attributively before a noun, so it's *possible* to hyphenate it; we can write "the already-quite-surprising idea". I don't recommend that, though; *already* and *quite* are both recognizably adverbs, so the hyphens aren't needed for clarity, and would be unnecessarily informal. (Not that there's anything wrong with being informal; but "the already quite surprising idea" is not the sort of thing you'd say if that's what you were going for!)